# Spark job SBT Assembly merge conflict when including Spark Streaming Kinesis ASL library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, amazon-kinesis

I started making a spark streaming job and got a producer up for kinesis endpoint.  After getting that working I started making a consumer but I ran into problems with building it.

I am using the assembly plugin to create a single jar that contains all the dependencies.  The project's dependencies are as follows.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "1.4.1",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
"c3p0" % "c3p0" % "0.9.1.+",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.4.1",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.33",
"com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-client" % "1.5.0"
```

)

When I run assembly, the files can compile but it fails during the merge phase with the error

```
[error] (streamingClicks/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/adam/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.10/jars/spark-network-common_2.10-1.4.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties
[error] /Users/adam/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties
```

This is caused when adding in the spark-streaming-kinesis-asl dependency.  How do I get around this?  I can mark the dependency as provided but then add the jar into the classpath but that's really not something I want to do.

Comment: What merge strategy do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the accurate solution in your case but you have to play with [merge strategy](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy) for these dependencies. It could be something like that:

```
lazy val strategy = assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly <<= (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case meta(_) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
}
lazy val core = (project in file("core")).
  settings(
    name := "core",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     ...
    ),
    strategy
  )
```

P.S. I recommend also assembly all dependencies in one "fatjar" project and provide code in dependent project. Then you can put fatjar on hdfs and package your actual code with `sbt package`. To run your code you  should provide fatjar and your package with `--jar` option.